# I want to achieve a specific row layout, but can't quite figure it out with Android

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

on a ListView but can't quite get the restraints on the items in the row layout.xml right, anyone have a suggestion?

here is my photo_album_row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photoAlbumTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photoAlbumDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoAlbumTitle"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewPhotoAlbumText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Open Album"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems to center the text okay if there's only the title displayed, otherwise there is overlap, this is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: you need to place your title (Summer 2016...) relative to the text (2015 was a great...)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I realized this, just needed to know how, and that was answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photoAlbumTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Hello world its title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photoAlbumDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hello world its description"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewPhotoAlbumText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPhotoAlbum"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Open Album"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good answer! It was close, I made a few changes to change it so it fit the requirements exactly, I'll edit them in and select it as the correct answer.